# Invalid default library path in Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I had Delphi XE7 installed for a couple of days. I realized that some paths (library path, debug path) were invalid (shown in gray color). Even though I changed NOTHING in Delphi settings I supposed it was my fault. So, I uninstalled Delphi XE and Delphi XE7 altogether and all related addons. Then I reinstalled Delphi XE7. RIGHT AFTER install I opened the IDE and checked the paths. They are still invalid. See attached image.

[image]

I also noticed that the $(Platform) variable is empty. I am on Win32. Shouldn't it be 'Win32'?

[image] 
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\debug is also gray (invalid).

What could be wrong with my installation?

Can anybody post this registry section:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\15.0\Library]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\15.0\Environment Variables]

**WARNING**
As Ken White suggested ***DO NOT ever press the 'Delete Invalid Path' button***. Embarcadero should get rid of that button now!

---

Hint:

A part of those 'default' settings (that are not anymore available in XE7) were move in another place. For example 'default' packages loaded by IDE at start up are now under 'Component -> Install packages' menu. Quite hidden because of the 'install' word.

Comment: There is no ($Platform) env var. It's substituted later. It doesn't look like you've really done a fresh install and made that screen shot. FastReports? Raize?

Comment: I also have grey entries in my XE2 installation. It looks as if they were there from the beginning and everything works fine.

Comment: This was reported in QualityCentral a long time ago (back in 2007) but it seems that untill now Embarcadero hasn't fixed it yet even thou the QC in question (http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=43085) is closed in year 2009.

Comment: You could have captured just the dialog rather than the large portion of the screen, which would have been more polite to mobile users and easier on the eyes for all of the rest of us. There's no need to post a giant image to display a small dialog. (+1 for the question, but please be more considerate of others in the future. Mobile users deal with small screens, and often pay for the data they download, so using images only when absolutely necessary and then using the smallest image possible is appreciated.)

Comment: I see nothing in what David said that required posting a huge image. You could have just commented that you've confirmed it by the fact your recent projects list is empty.

Comment: @Altar: To *mobile users*, absolutely, as is the extra data they are charged for monthly (view your image on a smartphone, for instance). Also to those who have limited bandwidth.

Comment: @KenWhite-You can disable loading of large images on your phone. OR even ALL images if your mobile data plan is really really small. You can also look for a service provide that will not charge you after you 'eat' your quota. I don't know about USA (that's a different planet) but in Europe this is the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine looks like this:

[image]

I have no problems with my installation. I think that everything is fine and the invalid directories are not important.

I'm not sure why `$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release` is deemed invalid in your screenshot. Perhaps that will resolve itself when you compile a project. However, I still think that everything here looks normal and that you will have no problems building projects.

Comment: My '$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release' is gray :(

Comment: Yes, I expect that will resolve itself when you create a new project and attempt to build it.

Comment: I just did that. It runs. I will check the registry now.

Comment: $Platform is still empty.

Comment: `$(Platform)` is filled in by the project. It's not an environment variable. It depends on your active config.

Comment: OK. I understand now! Thanks. But then, why 'Release' is gray? The folder exists!

Comment: My registry looks like yours too. I honestly don't think there's anything to be concerned about here.

Comment: @SirRufo Which I have in my IDE!!

Comment: @Altar: It doesn't *exist* until `$(PLATFORM)` is set at compile time based on the target platform you're compiling for (Win32, Win64, Android, etc). If your current target platform is Win32 (at **compile time**), the folder exists, because `$(PLATFORM)` is set to `Win32`. Until you're compiling, though, `$(PLATFORM)` is not set, and you do not have an actual folder on disk named `$(PLATFORM)`, so it is gray. (That's also why it's not set in your command window graphic, because the build process in the IDE has not set it.)

Comment: As far as `$(BDSUSERDIR)`, it doesn't exist until the IDE sets it, either, so there is no existing folder `$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports`. They're valid paths once the environmental variable is evaluated, but that doesn't happen when the dialog is displayed, so the path appears invalid.

Comment: One final note (which is really important): Do **NOT** click the *Delete invalid paths* button. It will remove the `$()` paths, which *will* break your IDE and require some work (or a reinstall) to repair. (EMBT should protect those entries from the cleanup, but it doesn't, and not having them will cause compiles to fail horribly. Been there, done that, wearing the T-shirt now.) @David: You might want to mention that in your answer as a courtesy.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the helpful comments. I'm now operating with just `$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release` and it seems fine for my needs. But I'm something of a loather of library path!

Comment: Yes, it will work; you add all the files to your project rather than adding them to the library path. Most (new) users don't do that, though, and as a result removing the invalid paths (which would include `$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\release`) can be fatal to the compile process in the IDE.

Comment: @KenWhite At work we prefer to be explicit about where our source code is coming from. But in any case, even when we use third parties, we incorporate the source into our source control repo so that we can control versioning. So for me, just `$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release` is perfect.

Comment: It works for me as well (I have the others listed in the dialog, but don't depend on them for anything important), but newer users don't know to do that (and many of them don't even know about any type of VCS yet).

Comment: Still I believe there is something wrong with the paths because my Delphi refuses to compile a project that worked with Delphi XE. The IDE complains that it cannot find the main DPK file - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881187/never-build-package-xxx-must-be-recompiled-sharing-violation?noredirect=1#comment44170926_27881187

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it's not related to the greyed out members of the global library path

Comment: The delete Invalide Path should block deletions of any path containing any kind of $() pairs, and only delete fully expanded paths that don't contain ok data.

And the Delete button should also be gray if setting focus on a line containing unexpanded {} pairs